# Difference between void methods and return methods?

Tags: methods

I'm wondering why is should choose one method over the other?

```
public static int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

public static void sumVoid(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println(x + y);
}
```

Comment: [try reading this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/importance-of-return-type-in-java) because both methods do two different things

Comment: I'd prefer the second method for debugging or showing the result inside the console. The first one could be helper-function which returns the result for another.

Answer (score 1):

In `public static int`, the int means that this function is going to return an `int` value.
However, in `public static void`, your function is not going to return any value, so its return type is `void`.

Adding on to this, if you just want to print out x and y in the function, you should use void. However, if you want to use x and y in a different function, you should use return, so that the other function(s) can use these variables, without the modifications that were made during the function. If you are not doing any modifications, then you should not need to return the variable, you you can just use void.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to get the value out of the function that performs the operation you can use function with the return type and when you want to perform operation but you don't want to store values you can print the value after every operation function call.